# can't downgrade zone.js angular

Tags: angular, npm, zone.js

I can't seem to be able to downgrade my zone.js file from 0.8.10 to 0.8.5. This is required since I'm having app issues on older phones (Huawei w/ Android 5.1.1).

Steps I've taken

```
npm install zone.js@0.8.5 --save
rmdir .\node_modules
npm cache clear
npm install
```

package.json shows "zone.js": "0.8.5"

I've made sure that zone is not globally installed and output shows that .8.5 is installed, but when I do 'npm view zone.js version' it shows 0.8.10 as output.

Anyone? :)

Answer (score 1):

That [command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view) is used to show the latest version of `zone.js` in the npm registry, not the version installed.

Use `list` for the version installed:

```
npm list zone.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.